# Does $-\frac{ \nabla f }{ || \nabla f || }$ point in the direction of steepest descent of $f$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

One way to interpret $\nabla f$ geometrically is that it yields a vector field who's direction is in the direction of the steepest ascent.

So, we can find the unit vector along this vector:

$$\frac{ \nabla f}{ || \nabla f || }$$

If we multiply it by the scaler $-1$:

$$ -\frac{ \nabla f }{ || \nabla f || } $$

Would this give me the unit vector along the **steepest descent**?

I needed the **unit vector along steepest descent**. After thinking a bit I came up with this but I am not sure if this is correct. In case it is correct, is there any proofy way to explain it so I can be more confident about it?

Comment: Yes.  Let's think about the case of a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.  Locally your surface should look line a plane so going the other direction along the line of the steepest **a**scent will give the directino of steepest **de**scent.  Try to find the directions of steepest ascent and descent on [this surface](http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/~pgeorge3/241_fall2006/dd.gif).  Can you see that they should be on the same line?

Comment: Why isn't any answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

To measure the extent of ascent/descent along a unit vector, you need the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).  For any differentiable $f$, the directional derivative along a unit vector $u$ is given by
$$
D_uf = \nabla f \cdot u
$$
Note, however, that by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality (or the "cosine formula" for the dot product),
$$
|D_uf| = |\nabla f \cdot u| \leq \|\nabla f\| \cdot \|u\| = \|\nabla f\|
$$
So, the lowest $D_uf$ can be is $- \|\nabla f\|$.  It suffices then to confirm that setting $u = -\nabla f/\|\nabla f\|$ yields this lowest possible directional derivative, namely $D_u f = -\|\nabla f\|$ (as desired).

Answer (score 1):

We know that:

$$f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v}) \approx f(\mathbf{x}) + \left < \nabla f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{v}\right> \;\;\;(1)$$

Let us find the vector that minimizes (1) (which is the vector of steepest descend):

$$\min_{\mathbf{v}} C(\mathbf{v}) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \left < \nabla f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{v}\right>$$
$$\text{s.t } |\mathbf{v}| = k$$

The constraint is added here, because otherwise, we would have an infinite result (since (1) is a linear function).

We also know that: $$\left < \nabla f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{v}\right> = |\nabla f(\mathbf{x})||\mathbf{v}| \cos \alpha \;\;\;(2)$$

From (1) and (2), we know that $C(\mathbf{v}) =  A\cos \alpha(\mathbf{v})$, where $A > 0$.

We conclude that $C(\mathbf{v})$ just depends on the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\nabla f$, hence $\mathbf{v}$ must be in the direction opposite to $\nabla f$ (when $\cos\alpha$ = -1)

So $\mathbf{v}$ must be:

$$\mathbf{v} = -k \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|} \;\;\;(3)$$

You can check for yourself that the $\mathbf{v}$ in (3) is the solution of the minimization problem.

Now if you select $k = 1$, then you will get that $-\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ is the steepest descent vector with unit size, as you intuited.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already agree that $\nabla f$ points in the direction of steepest ascent:

If we define the new function $g= -f$, then $g$ ascends precisely when $f$ descends, and so the direction of steepest ascent of $g$ is the direction of steepest descent of $f$. So
$$\nabla g = \nabla (-f) = - \nabla f$$
is the direction of steepest descent of $f$.